# view data to vb.net from sql query

Tags: sql, vb.net, postgresql, npgsql

i have table waw

```
id | month    | 2015 | 2014 | 2013 |

1  | january  | 2    | 4    | 6    | 

2  | february | 10   | 12   | 14   |

3  | march    | 16   | 18   | 20   |
```

i have a query `select "2014" from waw where month ='february'` and the result is `12`.

I want this query to be executed in `vb.net` can some one help me.

Comment: Can't you edit your question and paste the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit unclear(*at least for me*), Try like this:

*I assume that you're using  **Npgsql** as **.Net Data Provider***

```
Imports Npgsql

 Private Sub foo()
    Using conn As New NpgsqlConnection("pg_conn_string")
        Dim retVal As Integer
        Dim cmd As New NpgsqlCommand("", conn)
        conn.Open()
        cmd.CommandText = "select 2014 from waw where month ='february';"
        retVal = cmd.ExecuteScalar
    End Using
End Sub
```

you can use [ExecuteScalar](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/api/Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteScalar.html) because you are trying to get only a single value

Reference  : [npgsql command executescalar](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/wiki/User-Manual#user-content-getting-a-single-result-value-using-the-npgsqlcommandexecutescalar-method)

Comment: sir how about if i place 2013 in a variable . what is the query look like
 like this 
dim a as integer = 2013
cmd.CommandText = "select '"& ""a"" &"' from waw where month ='february';". but this code didnt work.

Comment: @MichaelBeray You should use `cmd.CommandText = "select " & a & " from waw where month ='february';"` (see [this](http://pastie.org/10205765))